Is there a way to configure Nx to always run tasks from the project root rather than workspace root?
I have a mixed repo with some non-JS projects that use make for running tasks. I am integrating these into an Nx monorepo by simply defining the tasks in each project.json using the generic nx:run-commands executor.
The problem is, if I use the convenient short form:
    "targets": {
        "test": {
            "command": "make test"
        }
    }

The target is run from the workspace root and make is unable to locate the Makefile. I can solve this using the long form and setting the cwd option:
    "targets": {
        "test": {
            "executor": "nx:run-commands",
            "options": {
                "command": "make test",
                "cwd": "apps/myapp"
            }
        }
    }

Of course, this will become highly repetitive and bloated as I need to do this for every target in every project.
Is there a way to set default options at the project level? It seems that the targetDefaults attribute is only available in the workspace nx.json, which will not work since each project needs a different cwd.
Alternatively, is there a way to configure the run-commands executor to have the project root as the default cwd?

Using targetDefaults is probably the best option. It can be combined with the {projectRoot} token to set the working directory dynamically.
Set the default configuration options in nx.json:
"targetDefaults": {
  "test": {
    "executor": "nx:run-commands",
    "options": {
      "command": "make test",
      "cwd": "{projectRoot}"
    }
  }
}

In the apps project.json configuration, the task needs to be defined to enable it for that project:
"targets": {
  "test": {},
}

No options need to be set for the task configuration in the project since they are all set in the defaults.
You may need to make changes if you have other tasks with the same name that might conflict with these defaults.
